# Configure Project : react-native-reanimated

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

Configure project `:react-native-reanimated`

Native libs `debug enabled: true`

Android gradle plugin: `7.0.4`

Gradle: `7.3.3`

building `Reanimated2`

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your `react-native-reanimated` to `v2.9.1` to fix the problem.

Then

```
cd android 
./gradlew clean
```

You can check more details and answers from [here](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3319)

Answer (score 0):

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
> Native libs debug enabled: false
> Android gradle plugin: 7.0.4
> Gradle: 7.3.3
> building Reanimated2
> [CXX1101] NDK at /Users/iasonasxrist/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529 did not have a source.properties file
> This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 2 but an SDK XML file of version 3 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.

Comment: Just check your **react-native version** :                                                                            If react-native <0.69 `npm install v2.8.0.` else `npm install v2.9.1.`

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by simply changing my compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion from 31 to 34.

Answer (score -1):

Android
cd android
echo "RUN ./gradlew --stop"
./gradlew --stop
echo "RUN ./gradlew cleanBuildCache"
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
echo "RUN rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/"
rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/
echo "RUN rm -rf .idea"
rm -rf .idea && cd ..
echo "RUN npm cache clean --force"
npm cache clean --force
echo "RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps"
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
echo "RUN npx react-native run-android"
npx react-native run-android

IOS

npm cache clean --force
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npx pod-install ios

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).